# extract values from a field in a line and append those values to this latter line

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have lines like this in a file

```
x;x;x;x;x;x;cmd="lbk_addcolumn TABLE_NAME_1 COLUMN_X";x;x;x;x

x;x;x;x;x;x;cmd="lbk_dropcolumn TABLE_NAME_2 COLUMN_Y";x;x;x;x
```

I wish to replace the field with "cmd" in the file to  something like this :

```
x;x;x;x;x;x;cmd="ColumnAdded TABLE_NAME_1 COLUMN_X || lbk_addcolumn TABLE_NAME_1 COLUMN_X";x;x;x;x

x;x;x;x;x;x;cmd="ColumnDropped TABLE_NAME_2 COLUMN_Y || lbk_dropcolumn TABLE_NAME_2 COLUMN_Y ";x;x;x;x
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Shouldn't the last line contain "lbk_dropcolumn" instead of "lbk_addcolumn" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Bash script:

```
while read ln; do
    out=`sed 's/\([^"]*\)"\([^"]*\)\(.*\)/\1"\2 || \2\3/' <<< "$ln"`
    out=`sed -e 's/lbk_addcolumn/ColumnAdded/' -e 's/lbk_dropcolumn/ColumnDropped/' <<< "$out"`
    echo "$out"
done < input.txt
```

where `input.txt` contains your lines

Comment: I have modified a bit my post. The previous one was a bit ambiguous. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r -e "s/(lbk_addcolumn.*)(\[.*\])\s*(\[.*\])/ColumnAdded \2 \3 || \1 \2 \3/g" \ 
-e "s/(lbk_dropcolumn.*)(\[.*\])\s*(\[.*\])/ColumnDropped \2 \3 || \1 \2 \3/g" input.txt
```

where `input.txt` is your content

Comment: Don't `cat | sed 'sedscript'`; just `sed 'sedscript' /path/to/file`.

Comment: I have modified a bit my post. The previous one was a bit ambiguous. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ugly sed regex patterns, If all the lines have the same fixed  format like your two lines (6*x;cmd="...";4*x), bellow alternative commands does the job in the file, without requiring a file read loop.

Key point (if format is steady across all lines) is the use of the `"` as delimiter, cutting the lines in 3 separate fields.

```
$ sed 's/lbk_addcolumn/ColumnAdd/;s/lbk_dropcolumn/ColumnDrop/' <(awk -F'"' '{if (($0=="")) print $0;else print $1"\""$2" || "$2"\""$3}' file.txt)
```

Or :

```
$ a=$(awk -F'"' '{if (($0=="")) print $0;else print $1"\""$2" || "$2"\""$3}' file.txt)
$ sed 's/lbk_addcolumn/ColumnAdd/;s/lbk_dropcolumn/ColumnDrop/' <<<"$a"
```

awk splits each line of file with `"` as delimiter.
if `$0=""` then it is a blank line, print the blank line and go on
else print all line fields in required order.

Finally sed replaces the first found text `lbk_addcolumn` with `ColumnAdd`.

Test:

```
$ cat e.txt
x;x;x;x;x;x;cmd="lbk_addcolumn TABLE_NAME_1 COLUMN_X";x;x;x;x

x;x;x;x;x;x;cmd="lbk_dropcolumn TABLE_NAME_2 COLUMN_Y";x;x;x;x

# sed 's/lbk_addcolumn/ColumnAdd/;s/lbk_dropcolumn/ColumnDrop/' <(awk -F'"' '{if (($0=="")) print $0;else print $1"\""$2" || "$2"\""$3}' e.txt)
x;x;x;x;x;x;cmd="ColumnAdd TABLE_NAME_1 COLUMN_X || lbk_addcolumn TABLE_NAME_1 COLUMN_X";x;x;x;x

x;x;x;x;x;x;cmd="ColumnDrop TABLE_NAME_2 COLUMN_Y || lbk_dropcolumn TABLE_NAME_2 COLUMN_Y";x;x;x;x
```

Same result can be achieved even only with awk and the use of the gsub awk function:

```
$ awk -F'"' '{if ($0=="") print $0;else {a=$2;gsub("lbk_addcolumn","ColumnAdd",$2);gsub("lbk_dropcolumn","ColumnDrop",$2);print $1"\""$2" || "a"\""$3;}}' e.txt
x;x;x;x;x;x;cmd="ColumnAdd TABLE_NAME_1 COLUMN_X || lbk_addcolumn TABLE_NAME_1 COLUMN_X";x;x;x;x

x;x;x;x;x;x;cmd="ColumnDrop TABLE_NAME_2 COLUMN_Y || lbk_dropcolumn TABLE_NAME_2 COLUMN_Y";x;x;x;x
```

awk better presentation:

```
    $ awk -F'"' '{
      if ($0=="") print $0;
      else {
        a=$2;
        gsub("lbk_addcolumn","ColumnAdd",$2);
        gsub("lbk_dropcolumn","ColumnDrop",$2);
        print $1"\""$2" || "a"\""$3;
           }
                 }' e.txt
```